# Evaluation of $\displaystyle \max_{0 \leq x,y,z\leq 1}\left(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x-xy^2-yz^2-zx^2\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**(1)** Evaluation of $\displaystyle \max_{0 \leq x,y\leq 1}\left(x^2y-xy^2\right)$.

**(2)** Evaluation of $\displaystyle \max_{0 \leq x,y,z\leq 1}\left(x^2y+y^2z+z^2x-xy^2-yz^2-zx^2\right)$.

$\bf{My\; Try::(1):}$ Let $\displaystyle f(y) = -x\cdot \left[y^2-xy\;\right] = -x\cdot \left[y^2-xy+\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^2}{4}\right] = -x\cdot \left[\left(y-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2-\frac{x^2}{4}\right]$

So $\displaystyle f(y) = \frac{x^3}{4}-x\cdot \left(y-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2\;,$ where $ 0 \leq y\leq 1$

So For $\max.\;,$ Put $y=0\;,1$  or $\displaystyle y = \frac{x}{2}$

So $\displaystyle \max \left[f(0)\;,f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\;,f(1)\right] = \max\left[0\;,\frac{x^3}{32}\;,x^2-x\right]\;,$ where $0 \leq x\leq 1$

Is my process is right, If not then how can i calculate $(1)$ and $(2)$

Help me, Thanks

Comment: (1)max is only one $y=\dfrac{x}{2}$. then $x$ take max.

Comment: (2) it is $(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)$.it is trivial $z=0$,so it become Q1.